# Fillna pandas doesnt fill all the missing values in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column Sulphate with missing values. I'm trying to fill in the missing values with predictions from a model I made. But, it does not fill in all the missing values. Instead it only fills in some of the missing values.

[image]

I have tried doing this but it only fills in 196 missing values not all.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmQFf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSkyl.png)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `fillna` uses the array `sulfate_predictions` to fill the null values. The only problem is, you're passing an array of length `n`, but the number of values to be filled is `n + x` where `x` > 0. Thus there are not enough values in the array to fill the null values

Comment: Are you trying to pass an array to fillna? this is not right

Comment: @gtomer read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), please.

Comment: So the number of my predictions(sulfate_predictions) is not enough to be fill the missing values? Isn't the number of predictions is the same as the number of missing values?

Answer (score 1):

`fillna`'s input is used by index, so if the first value in dataframe is not empty, the first value of the `sulfate_predictions` is ignored, and so on. You need to pass the array of the same size as your dataframe. Or try this:

```
df.loc[df['Sulfate'].isnull(),'Sulfate'] = sulfate_predictions
```

Comment: Looks like your method does not output any error but how do I keep it inplace=True?

Comment: It is not permanent on the original dataframe

Comment: This writes directly into the original dataframe (`df`). This works for me. Can you share what code you use?

Comment: I'm sorry I got the code wrong. It is inplace now but it only fills 196 missing values not all of them which is the problem I've been stuck with.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Could it be that `sulfate_predictions` contains `None`s?

Comment: No. The dataframe of it has non-null values. Here is the snippet of it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSkyl.png

Comment: It is weird how it only fills in 196 values. Like what happened to the other 585 values?